# Communication between web services on different servers

Tags: web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have 2 different webservices running on 2 different tomcat application servers (w/ axis2 web service engine)  (Webservice A runs on Server A and Webservice B runs on Server B).

How can web service A on Server A pass Data A (file) to Web Service B on Server B? I am new to web services and would appreciate any help in this regard. The webservices are in Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service A needs to be a client of service B. Service B should expose some method service A will consume (and pass required data using it). The process is as follows:

1. If suitable service method doesn't exist yet in service B then add new method  to service B's WSDL file.
2. Regenerate intefaces from extended WSDL file.
3. Create functional test for new service method .
4. Make service A a consumer of method  of new (extended) service.
5. Create acceptance tests for service A methods using service B's method  :-)
6. Implement new service method in service B.
7. Implement conusmer logic in service A.

Comment: Thanks but I actually need to know how to implement this. Can you point to any good tutorials which actually discusses end-to-end implementation of such a service?

Comment: I don't know a really good one, but quite nice example you can find here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier - I am specifically looking for a top-down web service implementation using WSDL. If you find something on it then please post it. Thanks for the help already!

Answer (score 0):

Expose a "send" web-service API on B and call it from A.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousends of ways, but with HTTP Protocol you can use: POST or PUT methods.
However, you'll need to write application on each side...